# Discord.js V12 messageReactionAdd only fires when bot reacts

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Upgrading my bot from V11 to V12.1.1 I have a messageReactionAdd as

```
client.on("messageReactionAdd", (reaction, user) => {
  console.log("Reaction added");
  if (user.id == client.user.id){return console.log("Reaction is from Lillette");}
  const chanid = reaction.message.channel.id;
  console.log(chanid);
  let chanchk = (reactchannels.indexOf(chanid) > -1);
  console.log(chanchk);
  if(chanchk === false){return console.log("Reaction not in a valid channel");}


  for (var i = 0; i < reactchannels.length; i++){
    if (reactchannels[i] == chanid && i == 0){arrayn = reactnames.one, arrayr = reactroles.one, console.log(`Success at i=${i}`);}
    else if (reactchannels[i] == chanid && i == 1){arrayn = reactnames.two, arrayr = reactroles.two, console.log(`Success at i=${i}`);}
    else {arrayn = [], arrayr = [];}
    if(arrayn.length !== arrayr.length){/*return*/ console.log("Arrays not equal length");}

    const emoji = reaction.emoji.name; //"cat";
    const guildmem = reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id);
    for (var e = 0; e < arrayn.length; e++) {
      if (emoji == arrayn[e]) {
        console.log(`Found emoji named ${arrayn[e]}, corresponding role = ${arrayr[e]}`);
        var findrole = reaction.message.guild.roles.cache.find(g => g.name === arrayr[e]);
        if (findrole == null) {return console.log("User has reacted with a valid emoji, but the role does not exist in the guild");}//End if no roles found
        guildmem.roles.add(`${findrole.id}`);//assign role
        return; //no need to continue loop if role found
      }//End of if
      //else {console.log(`No roles found for ${arrayn[e]}`);}
    }//End of for e
  }//end of for i
  if (arrayn.length == 0 || arrayr.length == 0){/*return*/ console.log("END -- arrayn or arrayr lengths are equal to 0");}
});
```

Yes it's untidy but It will not pass line 2 `console.log("Reaction added");` except when the bot reacts to a message, in which case it returns due to line 3. Channel/emoji/emojinames/arrayn/arrayr are defined above the code but don't seem relevant at this point.

Can anyone point me towards why a user (both myself and an alt account) does not register a reaction event (fire line 2) when using the same emoji in the same channel/message as the bot?

EDIT: In both cases the message reacted to IS sent AFTER the bot is turned on. And similarly a raw reaction event is included in the code below to grab and handle uncached messages (but not yet being debugged as the simpler, messageReactionAdd is not working).

Comment: Make sure that the message is sent after the bot started

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, have updated OP. Both instances message in question has been after the bot has been booted and I have a raw reaction event to grab uncached messages (but not up to seeing if that works yet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seemed to be having a conflict with the raw events below. Code above should work standalone.

Comment: If your question is answered please delete it or Mark this as the Accepted Answer with the Green tick